How does Grover's algorithm affect the MAC birthday bound and message lengths?
Grover's algorithm is said to reduce the strength of symmetric algorithms to basically half the number of bits in the key. I.e. AES-256 will have the strength of AES-128. What I've tried to understand is how MACs, for example HMAC, Poly1305, GMAC in GCM will be affected.
More specifically, given the birthday bound, would Grover's algorithm cause a reduction in the maximum length of a message before rekeying? If so how much?

"Grover's algorithm is said to reduce the strength of symmetric algorithms to basically half the number of bits in the key" - that is overstating it.  There are two things that get in the way - the fact that quantum computations are far more expensive than classical ones, and the nonparallelizability of Grover's.

And that's besides the relatively large number of logical qubits that are required for Grover. The best paper that I've found so far seems to be Breaking Symmetric Cryptosystems using
Quantum Period Finding. It comes to a different conclusion than many may expect, even though it uses Grover. Possibly also interesting is the paper "Attacks on Beyond-Birthday-Bound MACs in
the Quantum Setting". Less dramatic: it's probably $2^{n/2}$ where $n$ is the block size, which is usually the output size of the MAC as well.

@MaartenBodewes: that paper is completely uninteresting (and it doesn't use Grover's, it uses Simon's).  It assumes that the attacker can issue entangled queries and get entangled results.  This is literally the easiest attack to defend against - we literally don't know how to make an implementation where this attack applies.


More specifically, given the birthday bound, would Grover's algorithm cause a reduction in the maximum length of a message before rekeying?

No, not really.  However, to explain why, we need to look at what Grover's algorithm does.
What it does is take a public function $F(x)$, which takes an input and outputs either a 'true' or a 'false', and for most inputs, it outputs 'false'.  What it does is try to generate an input $x$ for which $F(x)$ outputs 'true'; if one in $k$ inputs generate a 'true', Grover's finds such an $x$ with an expected $O(\sqrt{k})$ evaluations of $F$.  Actually, there's some fine print involved, but we can ignore those points.
One point that we can't ignore is that $F$ needs to be public.  That is, Grover's algorithm needs to compute it (and to uncompute it) on an entangled state and get an entangled result.
In the normal cases of using Grover's, for example, looking for a hash preimage, this is not an issue.  In that case, we would define $F$ to be 'compute the hash of the image, and return 'true' if the hash is what we are looking for'.
On the other hand, if we're have some MACs inputs and outputs, and just look at those, we don't have a way to turn them into a Quantum Algorithm that we can evaluate for arbitrary inputs.  Hence, we cannot provide a function $F$ for Grover's to use.
What we could use Grover's for is to do a key search; we take a known message and a MAC, and have our $F(x)$ be "if we take $x$ as the MAC key, does it translate this known message into the known MAC" (and if the MAC is shorter than the key, we can do this for several known (message, MAC) pairs).  We have all the information needed to compute this $F$ function, and so we can implement it entirely on our Quantum Computer.  On the other hand, there isn't a way to use a long message to make this more efficient (and actually, it'd be more efficient with a short message).
Now, if we consider an entangled setup (where the attacker can provide entangled messages to the system under attack and get entangled MACs), then we can set up Grover's to do something.  However, that scenario is completely impractical (as I mentioned in the comments) and is of interest only to academics looking for something to write a paper about.
